# Why can't I get this Git alias to work?

Tags: git

I've installed git for windows. I want `com` to be an alias for `commit -m`, so that I can write for example

`git com "dumb commit message"`

and it works the same way as if I'd written

`git commit -m "dumb commit message"`

I added this line to the "gitconfig" file (why do these linux types have such a hatred of file extensions?):

```
[alias]
    com = 'commit -m'
```

This doesn't work. I get

```
error: pathspec 'dumb commit message' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I tried variations on the above syntax in "gitconfig" and I tried to define it from within Git Bash. I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: In Unix the file is `.gitconfig`, with a dot in front of it.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use quotes around the value, just the plain command:

```
[alias]
   com = commit -m
```

Comment: I closed Git Bash, edited gitconfig to remove the quotes, opened Git Bash again and tried again. The behaviour remained the same.

Comment: Hm, I tried this on an Ubuntu system with git 1.7.1 and it worked just fine. Maybe there is something special about this on Windows?